# Why does Lupin have his first transformation at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, werewolf

In Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkeban, Lupin, the werewolf, has to take a potion every full moon to keep his inner wolf under control. It causes him to miss class. Now, the first time it happens (the students are told he is sick), it's stormy outside, so the clouds would be covering the moon.

> " 'Sorry I'm late, Professor Lupin. I --' 　　But it wasn't Professor
>   Lupin who looked up at him from the teacher's desk; it was Snape.
>   　　'This lesson began ten minutes ago, Potter, so I think we'll make it
>   ten points from Gryffindor. Sit down.' "

> " 'D'you know what that --' (he called Snape something that made
>   Hermione say 'Ron!') '-- is making me do? I've got to scrub out the
>   bedpans in the hospital wing. Without magic!' He was breathing deeply,
>   his fists clenched. 'Why couldn't Black have hidden in Snape's office,
>   eh? He could have finished him off for us!'  　　Harry woke extremely
>   early the next morning; so early that it was till dark. For a moment
>   he thought the roaring of the wind had woken him. Then he felt a cold
>   breeze on the back of his neck and sat bolt upright -- Peeves the
>   Poltergeist had been floating next to him, blowing hard in his ear."

So when Lupin was "sick" the first time, it was storming really hard outside, so the moon wouldn't have been visible. But, later in the book it says

> "A cloud shifted. There were suddenly dim shadows on the ground. Their
>   party was bathed in moonlight. 　　Snape collided with Lupin, Pettigrew,
>   and Ron, who had stopped abruptly. Black froze. He flung out one arm
>   to make Harry and Hermione stop. 　　Harry could see Lupin's silhouette.
>   He had gone rigid. Then his limbs began to shake. 　　'Oh, my --"
>   Hermione gasped. "He didn't take his potion tonight! He's not safe!"
>   　　"Run," Black whispered. "Run. Now.' "

It says that "A cloud shifted. There were suddenly dim shadows on the ground. Their party was bathed in moonlight." and "Harry could see Lupin's silhouette. He had gone rigid. Then his limbs began to shake." Meaning that it's direct moonlight that causes the transformation. So why did Lupin transform the first time, if it was stormy outside?

Comment: I think this has been covered before, but it appears that he will turn no mater what on nights with a full moon, whether he sees it or not. as obviously if he just stayed in the house and never saw the moon he would never change if the moonlight itself was responsible, and being a werewolf wouldnt be a big deal at all. it seems the direct site of the full moon hastens the transformation.

Comment: You'll want to format those quotes correctly (highlight the quote, click the blockquote button, the one that looks like a left side speech mark).

Comment: @Himarm exactly what I was thinking, too.